# escript: /riak-1.1.2/rel/riak/erts-5.8.5/bin/nodetool

Tags: riak

I keep getting this error when trying to run riak commands.

The nodetool file does not exist in that directory. When I copy the nodetool file from 5.8.4 I start getting this error:

{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','start_clean.boot'}}

**EDIT**

I followed this great advice here: http://onerlang.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/fighting-with-riak.html. Now when I run riak start I get:
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
Error reading /abc/def/otp_src_R14B03/riak-1.1.2/dev/dev1/etc/app.config
{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','start_clean.boot'}}

**EDIT 2**
I seem to be getting this problem http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-November/006436.html.

Whenever I build from source (required for multiple nodes on the same machine) riak tries to user erts-5.8.5 whereas riak requires(?) erts-5.8.4.

Is it possible for me to tell to not use 5.8.5 and use 5.8.4 maybe?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Erlang installed? When building Riak is this from clean? (ie. `make distclean && make`)? I am able to build and run 1.1.4 on my Mac using 5.9.1 without any problems. Which version is the default install of Erlang?